# .htaccess - Open files without extension using .htaccess in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I downloaded a website, all files are coded in HTML and files do not have any extension.

My root domain is WordPress based.

I want to open all files as HTML using `.htaccess` - the files are in a subdomain.

I have tried this, think its for root domain only... I need help for subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What does this mean? "i want to open all files as html" Aren't those php files?

Comment: If you want to limit the application of the rule to a "subdomain" (so the requested host name, I assume), you need to add another `RewriteCond` comparing the HTTP_HOST to that host name: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$`

Comment: no all are html files only (html css js files)..not php for sure ...thank you for ur reply ... shud i add this code to  root .htaccess file or in subdomain folder... sorry im poor at coding..im trying to learn.. thank you anyhow :)

Comment: But you explicitly check if there is an existing php file with that base name... And also you explicitly rewrite the request to process a php file...

Comment: And what do you mean by "all files are coded in html" considering you also state that there are also css and js files... ?!?

Comment: what i meant..its a static website coded in html js and css ..not any server side or php coded website.. i got files without any file extension.. if add .html to them, then only i was able to open them.. but there are thousands of files like that.. it may take few weeks for me to rename all those files... so is there any .htaccess code to  access them?

Comment: The actual "files" don't have file extensions?! How exactly did you "download" this website?

Comment: It is still rather unclear what you actually want to achieve here. Your question should come with a proper description of what is located where in your file system, and examples of what URLs you want to rewrite to where exactly.

Comment: @DocRoot That actually makes perfect sense. 1980th style "file name extensions" are obsolete these days anyway.

Comment: @arkascha Except that Apache is dependent on the file extension in order to return the correct mime-type (`Content-Type` header), otherwise we need to manually set it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague as you've not given any examples of the URLs and file structure involved. However, if the HTML files do not have file extensions then it's quite probable that the `Content-Type` HTTP response header being sent from the server is either wrong or entirely absent (and reliant on the browser "content sniffing" - which is going to get mixed results).

We need to make some assumptions:

- All the HTML files (that do not have file extensions) do not contain a dot anywhere in the file path.
- The CSS and JS files do have appropriate file extensions ie. `.css` and `.js`, and are already returning the correct mime-type (`Content-Type` header).

  If these too don't have file extensions, then they would need to be contained in specific directories so we can set the appropriate mime-type accordingly. We would also need to create exceptions with our rules in order to avoid conflicts.

So, in order to get the browser to interpret these files as HTML we need to make sure that we are sending the correct mime-type (ie. `text/html`) in the `Content-Type` response header. (I assume this is not the case currently.)

For example, using mod_rewrite in the `.htaccess` file in your subdomain (which I assume is separate from your main domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)?$ - [T=text/html]
```

However, as noted above, if your static resources (JS, CSS, images, etc.) are also devoid of file extensions then we'll need to add conditions to the above rule and create additional rules for the different file/mime types.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
> ```

These directives that you posted in the question don't appear to have anything to do with your question, which has only added to the confusion in comments.